# How to use SetWinEventHook() function to get Active Window changed message

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I have been working on a project which needs to detect current active window and get the active window title continuously.
Can anyone explain me how to use **[SetWinEventHook()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx)** function to get **Active** **Window** changed message.
[ i used **GetForegroundWindow()** function with a timer to get the active window. That approach is not very accurate because of the timer. So i need to use it with SetWinEventHook() function. can someone explain me how to do that? ]

```
hEvent = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND , EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND ,NULL, 
WinEventProcCallback, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);


VOID CALLBACK WinEventProcCallback ( HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD dwEvent, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
      /* how to get active window message */
}
```

Comment: Here are great examples: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/25/10404940.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/10/26/10230020.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I have found the solution. [EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066(v=vs.85).aspx) Event is the missing piece. The system sends this event even if the foreground window has changed to another window. We can use this event to get the current active window.

```
VOID CALLBACK WinEventProcCallback ( HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD dwEvent, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
     if (dwEvent == EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND)
     {
         /* do something */
     }
}
```

Comment: Beware that the `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` event is not sent when a window is unminimized.

Comment: According to the MS docs,  `EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZEEND` is sent when a window is restored (unminimized). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/event-constants